# How to edit data flash variables in BQ34Z100 fuel gauge IC with an MCU?

Tags: batteries, texas-instruments, fuel-gauge

[image]

I have an 8s Lifepo4 battery pack ,I am using an TI BQ34Z100 fuel gauge Ic to calculate the soc of the battery pack but to configure the Ic for my battery pack I have to change the data flash configuration variables usually its done with bqstudio and an Evm but I dont have the luxury of owning own.The chip has an i2c interface to communicate with It,my question is can I use this interface to set the configuration variable on the chip,the datasheet does have lot of i2c commands to do it but can I use an Mcu like arduino to communicate and set the variables?.

BQ34Z100 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq34z100.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1655891643784&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fbq34z100)

Comment: If the datasheet walks you through the I2C commands, use a PC with an Aardvark or other USB->I2C interface to try them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data sheet has a step by step guide to build a pack and configure settings.

In general you read and write registers over a bus to store settings you want.

Yes any micro could be used to communicate with the chip.